# Solidity - ParserError: Expected primary expression when using var

Tags: mapping, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to create a struct and add mapping in such a way that it can be retrieved later on using its address using the below code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Courses {
    
    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
        var instructor = instructors[_address]; //ERROR HERE

        instructor.age = _age;
        instructor.fName = _fName;
        instructor.lName = _lName;
        
        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;

    }

}
```

However, I am getting an error at the line `var instructor = instructors[_address]`

The error is `ParserError: Expected primary expression`

I am unable to understand what the issue is and how to resolve it. Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solidity uses typed variables, doesn't have the generic `var` keyword (that is used in JavaScript for example).

---

When declaring [reference types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html#reference-types) (in your case `string` and `struct`), you need to specify their data location - in your case `memory` for the string argument. And either `memory` or `storage` for the struct depending on whether you want to set the values just in the context of the `setInstructor()` function (location `memory`), or if you want to set its values in the contract storage (location `storage`).

```
function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string memory _fName, string memory _lName) public {
     // either `memory` or `storage` depending on your use case
     Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];

     // ... rest of your code
```

---

There also is a syntax error on this line

```
instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
```

you can fix it by removing the `-1`

```
instructorAccts.push(_address);
```